# I want Handlebar {{#if}} logic inside of a Ember.Handlebars.helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, components, handlebars.js

I am converting someone else's code to Handlebars.js and I'm stuck on converting this tag to its `{{#handle-bar}}{{/handle-bar}}` counterpart.

The previous coder used an `{{#ifCond}}` to toggle what 'selected'. This is my component.

```
{{#dropdown-item }}
    {{unbound this.itemName}}
{{/dropdown-item}}
```

Here is the div i want converted to my component

```
<div class="dropdownItem" {{bind-attr value=formField_DropdownItemID}}{{#ifCond formField_DropdownItemID value}} selected{{/ifCond}} >
    {{unbound this.itemName}}
</div>
```

My first thought was to just pop the div's logic into the the component, like the next example, but this gave me an error.

```
{{#dropdown-item bind-attr value=formField_DropdownItemID {{#ifCond formField_DropdownItemID value}} selected{{/ifCond}} }}
    {{unbound this.itemName}}
{{/dropdown-item}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried `yield`ing in the template you have for dropdown-item as described here: http://emberjs.com/guides/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/?

Comment: Dropdown-item only represents one dom element and i want to know how to use these conditionals inside of handlebars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set those properties to compute. The syntax would be:

```
{{#dropdown-item selected=computedProperty value=formField_DropdownItemID}}
```

`computedProperty` can deal with your conditional logic. The whole idea is to pull that out of handlebars anyways. :)

Comment: This a simple and straight-forward solution. Thanks!